# What type of microcontroller do I have?

Tags: microcontroller

For my birthday I got a small NSOP-A Microcontroller in a kit and I was wondering if I could use it to convert analog signals to 8-bit digital signals for My raspberry pi. Anyway, that isn't the question.
I was looking to see how to program it and I could not find any documentation on what sort of architecture it used.
The Microcontroller I'm using is the HT46f47e(made by holtek).

What type of chip is it?
And how would I program it?

Comment: Datasheet at http://www.holtek.com.tw/productdetail/-/vg/46f4xe

Comment: Holtek provides a free toolchain for its 8-bit MCUs.

Comment: It seems to be a proprietary core (not ARM, not 8051, ...) But all the information you're looking for can be found on Holtek's site: the MCU datasheet (including pinout, architecture, memory model, I/O registers, instruction set, ...), the type of programming hardware you need, the toolchain, development environment, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The HT46f47e made by Holtek is a 8-bit high performance RISC architecture** microcontroller.  Designed especially for applications that interface directly to analog signals, such as those from sensors. (http://www.holtek.com/productdetail/-/vg/46f4xe)

**The main Features are**:

- 13 to 23 bidirectional I/O lines
- External interrupt input shared with an I/O line
- 8-bit programmable Timer/Event Counter with overflow interrupt and
  7-stage prescaler
- On-chip crystal and RC oscillator
- Watchdog Timer function
- PFD for audio frequency generation
- Power down and wake-up functions to reduce power consumption
- Up to 0.5us instruction cycle with 8MHz system clock at VDD=5V
- 4 or 6-level subroutine nesting
- 4 channels 8 or 9-bit resolution A/D converter
- 1 or 2 channel 8-bitPWMoutput shared with I/O lines
- Bit manipulation instruction
- Table read instructions
- 63 powerful instructions
- All instructions executed in one or two machine cycles
- Low voltage reset function
- Flash program memory can be re-programmed up to 100,000 times
- EEPROM data memory can be re-programmed up to 1,000,000 times
- Flash program memory data retention > 10 years
- EEPROM data memory data retention > 10 years
- ICP (In-Circuit Programming) interface
- Range of packaging types

**One of the possibles programmers is the EIC-300 of Holtek**.

http://www.elektronik-labor.de/Holtek/Holtek7.html

Comment: How would I program it using a raspberry pi without external hardware?

Comment: "8-bit high performance" sounds rather contradicting. "High performance" as in "at least it is faster than 8051" seems more accurate.

Comment: @BobWillett Rasp PI has nothing to do with this MCU whatsoever.

Comment: @Lundin aww.... I'll have to shed some cash

Comment: Is it possible to do it without any external hardware?

Comment: @BobWillett if you want to use the raspi as the programming hardware, it may be possible, but then you need some additional documentation (the In-Circuit Programming protocol, which is Holtek proprietary) that I haven't been able to find with a quick search (not described in the datasheet, and I couldn't find a specific document). But if that was your concern since the beginning, your initial question should have been more clearly formulated.

Comment: @Lundin It's probably a newspaper ad from the 1980s LOL :)